# Using both SlidingActivityBase and SherlockFragmentActivity to create a Sliding Menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I've been following this tutorial to create a sliding menu:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWTYQ2g597o

And because Im using Sherlock, I had to change my class declaration from this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity
```

to the following:

```
public class RggarbActionBar extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase
```

and now Im getting a NullPointerException whenever I use the getSlidingMenu() method which stays empty down there in my class and returns null.

Here is my whole class:

```
public class RggarbActionBar extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase  {
    protected ListFragment listFragment;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        listFragment = new RggarbSlidingMenu();
        SlidingMenu slidingMenu = getSlidingMenu();
        slidingMenu.setShadowWidth(15);//outsource these
        slidingMenu.setBehindOffset(60);
        slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSherlock().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new 
                   ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#680e96")));
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo_icon);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_items, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if(itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            toggle();
            return true;
        }
        else if (itemId == R.id.abFeed) {
            Intent feed = new Intent(this, Home.class);
            startActivity(feed);
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.abNotifications) {
            Intent notifications = new Intent(this, Notifications.class);
            startActivity(notifications);
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.abAddNewItem) {
            Intent addNewItem = new Intent(this, ItemAdd.class);
            startActivity(addNewItem);
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.abSearch) {
            Intent search = new Intent(this, SearchItems.class);
            startActivity(search);
            return true;
        } else {
            return onOptionsItemSelected(item); //watch out for this one. if any problems occur change to "return true"
        }
    }
    public class BasePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        private ViewPager mPager;

        public BasePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ViewPager vp){
            super(fm);
            mPager = vp;
            mPager.setAdapter(this);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                addTab(new RggarbSlidingMenu());
            }
        }

        public void addTab(Fragment frag){
            mFragments.add(frag);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position){
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return mFragments.size();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setBehindContentView(View view, LayoutParams layoutParams) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setBehindContentView(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setBehindContentView(int layoutResID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public SlidingMenu getSlidingMenu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void showContent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void showMenu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void showSecondaryMenu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setSlidingActionBarEnabled(boolean slidingActionBarEnabled) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is

```
@Override
public SlidingMenu getSlidingMenu() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

You are returning null from this method. You should add your code to return the slidingmenu instance **that you should have created elsewhere** (most likely in the OnCreate() method of your activity).

If you return null, that is exactly what you will get.

You would be better following the "[Simple Example](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#simple-example)" on the github page rather than implementing the `SlidingActivityBase` interface.

By implementing the interface you are saying that you want to handle all of the coding for the slidingmenu system and do not want to use the built in code.

Implementing an interface (what you are doing) is an entirely different thing to extending a base class (what is explained in the tutorial you are following).

Your choices are:

1. Forget the tutorial you have found as it does not apply to you and implement your sliding menu manually using the instructions [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#how-to-integrate-this-library-into-your-projects). This method does not require you to extend or implement anything and is the easier option.
2. You have the source code for both [ActionbarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) and [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). Change it so SlidingActivity extends the Sherlock Activity instead of the standard Activity.
3. Continue implementing the interface but you have to write the code for all of the implemented methods. Easier than it sounds as you can basically copy the code in the class **[here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingActivity.java)** with a minor adjustment to the class declaration like this.

   ```
   public class SlidingActivity extends Activity implements SlidingActivityBase {
   ```

   change to

   ```
   public class SherlockSlidingActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase {
   ```

Comment: how do i retrurn that instance

Comment: Instructions for using the library are already fully documented on the github page.

Comment: well I've read the instructions and still asking this question, so